# Time-minimizing trajectories in the presence of a strong wind on a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, optimal-control, semi-riemannian-geometry, finsler-geometry

I want to find the solution to the [Zermelo's navigation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_navigation_problem) in a specific case where I have a strong wind $W$. I would like to apply the geometric formalism explained [here](https://eracap.github.io/4talks/Finsler&spacetimes.html) or also [here on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5494). However, I am not a mathematician (I'm a physicist) and I can't really understand how to apply those theorems and concepts in practice.

I have already written a code in Wolfram Mathematica that solves the optimal navigation problem for mild winds (finding the geodesics of the corresponding Randers metric) and would like to do the same in the case of strong wind.

How can I do that?